# Need to do page refresh for reflecting new changes in the UI

Tags: angular6, angular-material-table

I am using angular6, and for showing some records i am using angular material data table.

When i  save or delete any customer, the changes are persisting in DB but not reflecting in the UI, i need to do page refresh for reflecting the changes.

I have given the code on below, first it will load customerList then customer component as a popup

I am doing Rest Call for CRUD operations.

```
customerList.component.ts
**************************

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { MatTableDataSource,MatDialog,MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { CustomerComponent } from '../customer/customer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource;
  searchKey:string;

  displayedColumns = ['name','actions'];

  constructor(private service : UserService,
              private dialog : MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchCustomer();
  }

  onSearchClear(){
    this.searchKey="";
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter(){
    this.dataSource.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  newCustomer(){
    this.service.initializeForm();
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent, dialogConfig).afterClosed().subscribe(() => this.fetchCustomer());
  }


  viewCustomer(customer){
    console.log(event.target);
    this.service.populateForm(customer);
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent,dialogConfig);
  }

  editCustomer(customer){
    this.service.populateForm(customer);
    console.log(customer);
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent,dialogConfig);
  }


    deleteCustomer(id){
    this.service.deleteCustomerData(id).subscribe(
      data => console.log("success", data),
      error => console.error("Error!",error)
    );
    this.populateTable();
  }

  fetchCustomer(){
    this.service.getUser().subscribe( results => {
      if(!results){

        return;
      }
      console.log(results);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
  })
  }
}

customerList.component.html
*******************************

<h1>Customer-List</h1>
<div class="search-div">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="newCustomer()" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>New Customer
    </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><a href>{{user.name}}</a></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to View" (click)="viewCustomer(row)" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
                <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
              </button>
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" (click)="editCustomer(row)" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Delete" (click)="deleteCustomer(row)" class="iconbutton" color="warn">
              <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>


customer.component.ts
**********************
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private customerService : UserService,
              public dialogRef : MatDialogRef<CustomerComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerService.getUser();
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.customerService.customerData(this.customerService.cutsomerForm.value).subscribe(
      data => console.log("success", data),
      error => console.error("Error!",error)
    );
   this.onClose();
  }

  onClose(){
    this.clearForm();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  clearForm(){
    this.customerService.cutsomerForm.reset();
    //this.customerService.initializeForm();
  }
}

customer.component.html
*************************

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>New Customer</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="customerService.cutsomerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #newCustomer="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer Name</label>
        <input [class.is-invalid]="customerService.cutsomerForm.get('name').invalid &&
                                   customerService.cutsomerForm.get('name').touched" formControlName = "name" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" formControlName="id"> 

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>userName</label>
        <input formControlName = "username" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>email</label>
        <input formControlName = "email" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input formControlName = "phone" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled] = !newCustomer.valid type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="clearForm()">Clear</button>
  </div>
```

user.service.ts

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Customer } from '../models/Customer.model';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

 private serviceUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  // private findAllCustomers = "http://localhost:8080/findAllCustomers";

  // private insertNewCustomer = "http://localhost:8080/addCustomer";

  constructor(private http : HttpClient,
    private fb : FormBuilder) { }

  cutsomerForm = this.fb.group({
    id : [''],
    name : ['',Validators.required],
    username : [''],
    email : [''],
    phone : ['']
  })

  initializeForm(){
    this.cutsomerForm.setValue({
      id : '',
      name : '',
      username : '',
      email : '',
      phone : ''
    });
  }

  getUser() : Observable<Customer[]> {
      return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }

  customerData(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.post<Customer>(this.serviceUrl,customer);
  }

  populateForm(customer){
    this.cutsomerForm.setValue(customer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving or deleting a customer from the table, but the `dataSource` is using the data that you have already fetched from the database. It cannot get the updated data unless you manually do it.

While saving a new customer, you'll have to make the `getUser()` request again ( or push the customer object in the `results` variable) and initialize the `dataSource` again.

While deleting, again, either make the call again, or iterate through the result variable, find the customer that was deleted, remove it from the array, and reinitialize the `dataSource`.

Comment: thats correct, thanks for your answer.

The home page is CustomerList component, from there i am opening a dialog box and there i am doing the adding, deleting each customer, that each Customer Component. I hope i am clear with the explanation.

"this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent,dialogConfig);"

So once i will submit customer component, i need to call customerList component by passing the object or what?

Comment: @mohan if you're routing somewhere else after submitting, then there's no issue, the component will automatically make the request because of the function call in `ngOnInit()`.

If you're staying on the same screen, just make a call to the `getUser()` function after the save (or delete) request is completed.

Comment: customerList Compoenent is the parent one and in this compoenent i am displaying all the records. After clicking on the new Customer button which is present on this page i am opening a dialog box which is Customer Component and in this component i am saving new Customer and closing the dialogBox, thats why issue is coming, i am not able to link this dialogBox and the parent component.

Comment: the below method is from the dialogComponent. Like this i am submitting the page and closing the dialog.
  onSubmit(){this.customerService.insertCustomerData(this.customerService.cutsomerForm.value).subscribe(
   data => console.log("success", data),
   error => console.error("Error!",error)
    );
  this.customerService.getUser().subscribe( results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
    this.onClose();
   }

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz so it's easier to understand?

Although, wrap the whole service call to getUser `this.service.getUser().subscribe(..)`in the `ngOnInit()` into a separate function (say, `getUsers()`), and then call that function in `ngOnInit()`, and after receving the success response from the save or delete request. Some thing like this, `data => { console.log('success', data); this.getUsers(); }, error => ... this.onClose();`

Comment: Hi @Akash, i had edited my question with sample code, did you find anything?

Comment: @mohan Hi, Mohan, it's almost right. The only change that I think you need to make is that you need to wait for the add or delete calls to finish before calling `this.onClose()`, which is invoking the `fetchUsers()` function.  

Either 1: Put the `this.onClose()` inside the response of the http call, or
2: when the call is finished, i.e after `data => console.log("success", data),
      error => console.error("Error!",error)` call `fetchUsers()` again.

Comment: if i want to show some message of operation...like delete operation is successful or something after button clicked, which component will be good?

Comment: @mohan If you don't want to put much work into it, you can just use a variable for success or failure message and show it under the form after the corresponding condition of success or failure.  

However, I like to use a pop-up dialog to show the success or failure message. I have to create that component just once, and I can use it anywhere in my angular app to show success/error messages (or to take user input).

Answer (score 2):

Akash's approach is correct. In addition to his approach you should use [afterClosed()](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogRef) method to link MatDialog to current component and get notified when the dialog is closed. After the dialog is closed, just fetch users again.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  newCustomer(type) {
    this.service.initializeForm();
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    dialogConfig.id = type;
    this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent, dialogConfig).afterClosed().subscribe(() => this.fetchUsers());
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(results);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
  }
```

Also if you share the code for deletion and `CustomerComponent` it would be easier to analyse any potential problems.

Comment: i don't see the code for deleteCustomer in customerList.component.ts